# Sync or update code from gitlab to Azure repos

Tags: git, synchronization, gitlab, azure-repos

We are working on migrating our code base from Git lab to Azure repos. We already migrated initial code base, since parallel development work is going in in gitlab we want to periodically merge the changes to azure repos. (including al branches and commit history) With the version or permission of Azure repos we have, we can only merge changes between branches and not from other repos (gitlab)

Can you please suggest is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with GitLab [Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/)

These instructions are specific to Azure App Service but should work for other Azure services:

1. Browse to your app in the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)
2. In Azure, go to *Deployment* > *Deployment Center*
3. Select *Source* > *Local Git*, then click *Save* near the top
4. Go to the *Local Git/FTPS credentials* tab near the top
5. Under *User scope*, create a new username and password and click Save

   (Azure creates a username for your application under *Application scope*; confusingly enough the username is everything after the backslash (`\`). Unfortunately [GitLab won't accept it as it starts with a dollar sign](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/211716).)
6. In a new browser tab/window, open your GitLab project
7. Go to *Settings* > *Repository*
8. Find *Mirroring repositories* and click *Expand*
9. In Azure, copy the *Git Clone Uri* and paste it into *Git Repository URL* in GitLab

   e.g. `https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/yourappname.git`
10. In GitLab, modify the *Git repository URL* to insert the username you created

    For example, if you created this username: `yourappname`

    *Git Repository URL* should now be: `https://yourappname@yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/yourappname.git`
11. In GitLab, set *Mirror direction* to *Push*
12. In GitLab, paste the password you used into *Password*
13. In GitLab, click *Mirror repository*